# Two calls to cycle, only one appears to work. Why?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm curious by the two `tikzpicture`s below behave differently.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (t1)  at  (0,0)   {};
  \node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (t2)  at  (1,0.5) {};
  \node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (t3)  at  (3,4)   {};
  \draw[color=red,line width=4pt] (t1) -- (t2) -- (t3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace*{\fill}
versus
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \draw[color=blue,line width=4pt] (0,0) -- (1,0.5) -- (3,4) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `cycle` makes sense for points and coordinates but not on `node`s. Add `coordinate` to the options of `node`s with no `inner sep` and they are same.

Comment: If you use nodes, TikZ applies a little magic so that the lines are only connected to the border of the nodes. The red path consists of several move-tos and line-tos. The function of `-- cycle` is the same as in `\path (<some coordinate>) -- cycle`. You can either use `coordinate`s instead of nodes, add `(t1)` instead of `cycle` or use `.center` with every node depending on what you want to do. The same problem arises if you want to `fill` that triangle which corners are the nodes. It won’t work because you only have two simple lines.